# Assertion Error during Pip installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, assertion

I use Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14p.

I'm giving as input `pip list`, but the process fails. In the following picture you can see where and how it fails:

[image]

Does anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: What pip version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had assertion errors during an pip install.

I was using a `--no-cache-dir`. python 3.6.7, pip 19.

removing the `--no-cache-dir` flag fixed it for me.

Comment: Assertion Error during Pip installation, is what i googled. was my error, and this is what I did to fix it. THis answer happended to be the first hit. so this might be usefull.

Comment: Had a similar error. Removing the --no-cache-dir fixed. Thank you!
```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 176, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 346, in run
    session=session, autobuilding=True
  File "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/wheel.py", line 886, in build
    assert have_directory_for_build
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading your pip version should remove the error.

`sudo pip install -U pip`

Comment: @J.Doe it is customary to click the checkbox  on the  answer that solves your problem best.

Comment: Fixed it for me in 2022. I was running `pip install -r requirements.txt` and was receiving an `AssertionError` on it running `setup.py`. Running `apt install python3-pip` on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS downloaded `pip-22.0.2`. Running the above command updated it to `pip-22.3.1`, which worked.